# Android Studio массив ссылок на картинки

Tags: java, android

Сейчас есть такая штука

```
private Integer[] mThumbIds = { R.drawable.card1, R.drawable.card2,
        R.drawable.card3, R.drawable.card4, R.drawable.card1, R.drawable.card2,
        R.drawable.card3, R.drawable.card4, R.drawable.card1, R.drawable.card2,
        R.drawable.card3, R.drawable.card4, R.drawable.card1, R.drawable.card2,
        R.drawable.card3, R.drawable.card4};
```

А надо так чтобы оно само это делало...

То есть есть папка (drawable) в неё будут добавляться изображения (не уверен что делаю все правильно, но да ладно) и программе должно быть без разницы сколько там изображений и как они называются, она должна брать и составлять подобный массив...

Прошу прощения за глупый вопрос, но чет я уже перегорел с это Android Studio и не могу нормально гуглить, а вопрос относительно срочный (до этого прогал на C#, да ещё и в Unity)

В итоге погуглив, а затем погуглив ещё раз я осознал что все делаю не правильно и что в drawable должны быть только нужные программе изображения типа icon или background (это также подметил @Jarvis_J, спасибо ему), а мне нужно нечто иное, так что теперь я буду создавать папку непосредственно в корневом хранилище устройства (или как это назвать, это я ещё не гуглил, но надеюсь разберусь) и туда уже добавлять картинки которые может брать, добавлять, удалять пользователь...

 Далее я буду проверять картинки на то что они картинки и добалять в список

(пока нашел примерно такой вариант)

```
Files.find(PATH, 1, (p, a) -> a.isRegularFile() && p.getFileName().toString().endsWith(".txt")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Ну и работать непосредственно с этим списком, список будет обновляться каждый раз когда обновляется Activity (переход на другую Activity и обратно должен обновить список) это вроде делается через какой-то стандартный метод

Comment: если устроит - есть простой вариант создания подобного массива при условии что все файлы называются одинаково и по порядку, например: "card0", "card1" и т.д. Единственно - нужно будет вручную указывать конечное число

Comment: Увы, @Jarvis_J, но до подобного яб додумался, а тут проблема в том что непосредственно пользователь может добавить в папку N-ое количество файлов с XXX названием где X это полнейший рандом...
Но все равно спасиб :)

Comment: пользователь не может добавлять в папку drawable файлы, так как они "зашиваются" в приложение на этапе компиляции

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку идентификатор `R.drawable.blahblah` это статическое поле сгенерированного класса `R.drawable`, типа:

```
public final class R {  
    public static final class drawable {  
        public static final int blahblah=0x7f020000;  
    }  
}
```

То на ум приходит только рефлексия, нечто типа:

```
Field[] fields = R.drawable.class.getFields();
for(int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++){
    mThumbIds[i] = fields[i].getInt(); //
}
```

Дополнительно, конечно можно и нужно обложить проверками - поле статическое, не статическое, каталог тот, не тот...